# handle <NULL> value in JSON array in python

Tags: python-3.x, null

i have an array of JSON objects that arrived from the source I can't control, and sometimes there are  values, like this:

```
[{"name": "HDD", "brand": "Samsung", "price": "$100"},
        <NULL>,
        {"name": "Mouse", "brand": "Logitech", "price": "$10"}]
```

is there any way to handle it in python? I'm getting a syntax error on reading the value.
i tried to put it this way:

```
try:
products = sorted(products, key=lambda k: k['price'], reverse=True)
except SyntaxError:
print("Error")
```

but no luck.

Comment: what's the `type(products[1])` ?

Comment: sorry, the products = [{"name": "HDD", "brand": "Samsung", "price": "$100"},
          <NULL>,
            {"name": "Mouse", "brand": "Logitech", "price": "$10"}]

Comment: I'm not asking about all `products`, I'm asking what does `print(type(products[1]))` show to you

Comment: if i keep an array like in example, it give me an Syntax Error right away. in case I remove the <NULL> from the array it returns me <class 'dict'>

Comment: post the context where the `products` are constructed/returned

Comment: it-s returned by proprietary library written in C: products= self.get_data() , i do not have a control over the value returned. it returns always an array of 10 elements, from time to time one of them is NULL

Comment: Strange thing is that i can print the "products" value when it is received but it fails when I start to parse it in code I run, but in the online compiler, I can't even print it.